# Disable free minutes in Gitlab Runner

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-runner

I currently have an instance in AWS running the pipelines in docker using runners.

Until yesterday everything was going great running everything in the instance, but today it has used the Gitlab runner again.

[image: Runner on AWS EC2]

[image: Gitlab Runner]

I was searching for a while for information on disabling running runners in Gitlab but didn't find much.

Is there a way to disable these free Gitlab minutes so I can always use my own AWS-hosted runner?

Comment: As far as I remember for Gitlab, you should label your Gitlab runner and define, that only labeled runners should used by your repositories (the logic would be, that the label should match). If you will label all your runners, using e.g. "aws", than you can be sure, that only your own runners within AWS (installed on an EC2 instance) will be used, if you also label your repository (or the config of your gitlab runners). Did the same for github action runners to add labels to prevent the usage of shared runners.

Comment: Am I correct in presuming that you want to disable the shared runners at the instance level, rather then group? If it was about group level, I'd be able to help